# Can't access to cookies with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

i can't access to the cookies stored in localhost.

[The cookis are already stored (view image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbdB0.png)

[When i try to display, i get undefined (view image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5jiB.png)

Here is my js code for display :

```
var app = angular.module("Authentification", ['ngCookies']);
app.controller("log", ['$cookieStore', '$scope', '$http', function($cookieStore, $scope, $http) {

    $scope.typeEmploye = $cookieStore.get('typeEmploye');
    alert($scope.typeEmploye);

}]);
```

Comment: `$cookieStore` service is deprecated, what version of angular are you using?

Comment: Ok, do you have `ngCookies` module installed?

Comment: I imported angular-cookies.js in my html file.

Comment: Was that cookie set not by `$cookieStore`?

Comment: i set the cookies like this  : $cookieStore.put('typeEmploye', $scope.user.type);
I realy can't undestand what's wrong with this.

Comment: It seems that you are doing everything right. Could you provide the whole code so I could reproduce the bug on my machine?

Comment: I posted the whole code in a second answer. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Here is my js code where i store the attribute in cookies after getting the result from my rest API.

```
var app = angular.module("Authentification", ['ngCookies']);
app.controller("main", ['$cookieStore', '$scope', '$http','$location',
function($cookieStore, $scope, $http, $location) {

$scope.user = [];
$scope.type=[];

$scope.auth = function() {
    $http.get("/Employe/authentification?login=" + $scope.log + "&password=" + $scope.pw)
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data) {
                $scope.user = data;
                $cookieStore.put('typeEmploye', $scope.user.type);
                $cookieStore.put('Authentified',true);


                $scope.type=$cookieStore.get('typeEmploye');
                if($scope.type == "gerant"){

                    window.location.href = "/Gerant/index.html";
                }
                else if($scope.type == "cuisinier"){

                    window.location.href = "/Cuisinier/index.html";
                }
                else if($scope.type == "servant"){

                    window.location.href = "/Servant/index.html";
                }
                else{
                    window.location.href = "/error";
                }

            }
            else{
                alert("Login ou mot de passe incorrects");
            }

        }).error(function(data, status) {
            alert("Problème dans le service d'authentification");

        });

};


}]);
```

The information is stored in cookies. But, when i go to an other page ( with a different js file), i can't get the cookies. here is the js code.

```
var app = angular.module("ger", ['ngCookies']);
app.controller("main", ['$cookies', '$scope', '$http','$location',
function($cookies, $scope, $http, $location) {

var Type = $cookies.typeEmploye;
alert(Type);
}]);
```